# Trigger file download without the anchor element

Tags: download, anchor

When using the anchor tags download attribute, the user must click on the link for the file to download. How do trigger a file download without the anchor tag? I tried using the JavaScript download() function, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can click the button via for eg.

```
<a href="#" id="someid" style="display:none">Download</a>
```

In Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a#someid').attr({target: '_blank', 
                    href  : 'http://localhost/directory/file.pdf'}).click();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry I do not have JQuery downloaded.